# Cómo puedo cambiar nombres de archivos en Visual Estudio Code y que se cambien automáticamente todas las referencias?

Tags: vscode

Estoy haciendo una página con archivos html js y css, con visual estudio code. Tengo que cambiar los nombres de algunos archivos y quiero que se cambien automáticamente todas las referencias dentro del código.
No sé si es necesario instalar alguna extensión.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buen día, recuerda que es importante realizar una búsqueda o investigación previa antes de publicar una pregunta. Una búsqueda rápida en Google "vscode refactorizar" devuelve [esta página](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring) en el primer enlace. Ahí dice que si oprimes `F2` puedes refactorizar desde variables hasta nombres de archivos. Algunos lenguajes no lo soportan según el artículo.

Comment: Sobra con la herramienta de búsqueda y reemplazo que tiene vscode. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_find-and-replace

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Mi pregunta es para ver si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con archivo html y js. Con F2 y refactorizar no me da la opción. Yo quiero que se cambien automáticamente las referencias, con buscar y reemplazar sería un trabajo muy grande.

Comment: F2 no es buscar y reemplazar, ¿Intentaste utilizarlo?

Comment: Sí claro, pero solo se cambia el nombre del archivo y no las referencias